# Charts not getting plotted on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, core-plot, ios5.1

I am using Core Plot to draw charts in my iOS application. The charts were getting plotted nicely till I was using core plot version 1.0. I just upgraded my core plot to version 1.2 and tested it on iOS 6 and all was looking OK there. But when I ran the same code on iOS 5.0 and 5.1, my bar charts got vanished and it is now showing me just a blank screen with two axes plotted. Bellow is the screenshot for the same[image: Blank Graph]

The problem occurs only for bar graph and scatter plot whereas pie charts are getting plotted correctly. I am using Xcode version 4.5. If anyone knows how to deal with this problem, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue with Core Plot 1.2. You can use Mercurial to pull the latest code with the fix from Google Code.