# Core Plot on iOS 5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have faced a bug using CorePlot on iOS5. I have installed Mercurial, launched Terminal and downloaded the latest version of the source using this command

`hg clone https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/`

I have compiled a new library and have copied over with the files from the CorePlotHeaders folder that came with the source. I have cleaned my project and reinstalled the app.

However, I'm still facing a problem typical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557186/charts-not-getting-plotted-on-ios-5)

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use an early version of core plot and wait fix unless you really need new features of 1.2. I have used 1.0 with iOS5. It's good enough for most senario I need.